# How long does it take to amend inventorship on a published patent after the paperwork is submitted to the USPO?

Tags: ownership

They are amending this patent to include 2 inventors not on the patent that should have been.  How long does it take before the USPO adds that amendment?

In reference to the patent: [US20120100313](https://www.google.com/patents/US20120100313)